# How can we reshape a matrix into a matrix of matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a `10*1300` matrix where each block of `10*10` values is an image. We can say that we have `130` images in a row. I want to rearrange this matrix so that I get all these images rearranged in `13` rows and `10` columns, where each `(row,col)` location is a `10*10` image. How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

**Example:**

> I have a `10*1300` matrix where `row=1:10` and `col=1:10` represents the
>   first image, `row=1:10` and `col=11:20` represents the second image and so
>   on. Therefore we have `130` images arranged side by side horizontally. I want to arrange these `130` images in such a way that first `10` images are arranged in first horizontal pane,next `10` images are arranged in a second horizontal pane and so on, thus getting `13` horizontal panes with `10` images in each pane.

Comment: 13 rows and 10 columns count for 130 data while the original set is 13000.

Comment: @il_raffa I have edited the question. Kindly check. BTW the question itself was self explanatory without this editing also.

Comment: Can you breakdown your problem into a smaller one and explain it with actual matrix/ces ?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I have provided an example. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, that actually makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of reshape and permute:

```
blk_size = 10;   % # of rows/columns in each block
blks_in_row = 10;

% reshape M matrix -> output in N
% you should first check that the dimensions of M are correct
N = reshape(M, blk_size, blk_size*blks_in_row, []);
N = permute(N, [1 3 2]);
N = reshape(N, [], blk_size*blks_in_row);
```

You can combine these three lines into one if you wish, but I expanded them out to give a better idea of what's going on.

The first line makes a 3D array with each 10x100 row of the output matrix is a plane. The second line permutes this matrix so that the planes become columns, and the third reshapes to a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to rearrange your matrix:

```
% suppose image is a defined matrix which is 10x1300

rearranged = [];
for i = 0:12
    startIndex = 100 * i + 1;
    endIndex = startIndex + 100 - 1;
    rearranged = [rearranged; image(:, startIndex:endIndex)];
end
```

the `rearranged` matrix is what you want.

Comment: What purpose it does? We already have the initial matrix what you have obtained in rearranged.

Comment: You will get a matrix which 130x100. In your language, in each row you will get 10 images.